Adding videos to VLC
How can I add video files to an Android tablet so that it can be played by VLC? There isn't an obvious way to do this with the app.

VLC automatically searches /storage and adds everything to its initial screen. Where exactly are you saving your files?

@ChanganAuto I am trying to figure out how to add the video files to the tablet.

You copy them from another device with cable, download them from some website or network share, any other means? If you don't have any videos yet on the device's storage why even mention VLC? This seems nonsensical...

I just tried it and it does indeed scan all your files at the startup.  You do have to give it All Files Access.
In addition, there is a Browse button at the bottom and you can search for files.
It is also documented

Using VLC in Android
When you launch the app, it will scan for all the media files on your phone/tablet and display it on the main screen. The app has evolved over time and the latest version is different than how it started out.

From vlchelp
